# How can I write some logic based on what page I am on using razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view which is displayed on the top right of every one of my pages. It has a link but this it needs to change based on the page that I am on.  So if I am on the home page, I need to display a login link in my partial view but if I am on the login page, I need to display a registration link.  Anyone know how to do this using razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the current action and controller from RouteData:

```
@{
    string controller = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string action = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    ... decide what to render
}
```

But obviously a much better way is to write a custom HTML helper that will generate the proper link based on the context.

Comment: I have solved my problem in a different way but based on my question, this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [layout](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) feature of mvc to make your views have a common look & feel, and then use the `@section` feature (also described in the link) to render a part which differs from page to page

**EDIT**

Implementing the `@section` feature:
Within the _layout.cshtml:

```
@*if section is optional for some pages*@
@if (IsSectionDefined("Link"))
{
  @RenderSection("Link")
}
```

Then, within each page (index.cshtml in my case):

```
@section Link
{
 <a href="#">the link</a>
}
```

The section is defined using a unique name, and later on rendered in the expected place in the layout, using the same name. 
 I think its a bit more of a clear design than relying on information from the routing, if the link is only view-dependant, because theoreticaly, at least, the view doesnt have to be aware of the routing engine/controllers which caused it to be rendered at first place.

Comment: that already gets done by default when you create an MVC project but I don't know how to make it differ from page to page, that's actually my question

Comment: added a sample for `@section` usage

Answer (score 0):

Add both links to the partial and use a jquery to hide it for a specific page on document ready.

So on the login page, do:

```
$('#registerPartialLink').hide();
```